# Need help getting my points per hour function to work properly

Tags: vb.net

I'm having difficulty getting my function to work right.
This function is supposed to estimate how many points per hour the user would get but instead it shows way too many numbers.

```
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Private Function PointsPerHour(gainedpoints As String, totalpoints As String)

    Dim firstvalue = gainedpoints
    Dim secondvalue = firstvalue
    Dim thirdvalue = totalpoints

    Dim varJWG0 As String = "Points: "
    Dim varJWG1 As String = thirdvalue
    Dim varJWG2 As String = " Points Per Hour: "
    Dim varJJM0 As Double = Double.Parse(thirdvalue.Replace(",", String.Empty)) - Double.Parse(secondvalue.Replace(",", String.Empty))
    Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = Now - DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime
    Dim dbl_ As Double = varJJM0 / timeSpan.TotalHours * -1.0
    Return (Convert.ToString(varJWG0 & varJWG1) & varJWG2) + dbl_.ToString("0.00")

    End Function
```

Even if I do `PointsPerHour(9, 91)` it still outputs more than 1000.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see why it's behaving like that? Your code also needs refactoring

Answer (score 1):

So I am not entirely certain what it is that this method is trying to achieve in your current implementation.

Firstly the values firstValue and secondValue are the same, also firstValue does not seem to be used apart from assigning to secondValue, which just seems redundant to me.

The first problem I can see is that you have no time in this function. The timeSpan you are using to hold presumably the totalHours is not holding a useful value. you are subtracting Now from Now.ToLocalTime. You will either get 0 or your timezone offset from this equation.

Basically; assuming your 9, 91 example; you are getting ((91-9)/timeSpan) * -1).

If 9 is the points you are earning per hour, and 91 is total points, then 91/9 = hours. or if you give the hours 9 * hours = 91 (in this case 10.1).